# How is a range generated when rangeTo() is not defined in your class

Tags: kotlin

I'm working through the Kotlin Koans, and I don't understand what's happening behind the scenes for the [Conventions - Ranges](https://play.kotlinlang.org/koans/Conventions/Ranges/Task.kt) koan.  I've created the following test case in IntelliJ using their class definition.

```
data class MyDate(val year: Int, val month: Int, val dayOfMonth: Int) : Comparable<MyDate> {
    override fun compareTo(other: MyDate): Int {
        if (year != other.year) return year - other.year
        if (month != other.month) return month - other.month
        return dayOfMonth - other.dayOfMonth
    }
}

fun checkInRange(date: MyDate, first: MyDate, last: MyDate): Boolean {
    return date in first..last
}

fun main() {
    val first = MyDate(2013, 12, 1)
    val last = MyDate(2014, 3, 1)
    val date = MyDate(2014, 1, 1)

    println(checkInRange(date, first, last))
}
```

I haven't defined how a range of MyDate objects would be constructed using `rangeOf()`.  I doubt that the compiler is smart enough to automatically generate a rangeOf function that is aware that months wrap around at 12, and days of the week at 31.  I figured it just generated a range for each of the data members of MyDate, using `rangeTo()` or `downTo()` as appropriate.  If that's the case, this case should fail when checking months, as `(12 downTo 3).contains(1)` should be false.  Nonetheless, it's returning true.  How is the range actually being generated, that allows this code to work?

Comment: You implement https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparable/. There's actually nothing here doing wrapping, you can create Date objects you'd consider invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `Comparable<T>.rangeTo()` extension function in the standard library. That’s what you’re using if you haven’t defined your own.  It just returns a Range, not some type of progression that you could iterate, so it’s irrelevant whether there are wrap-arounds or how many steps there are between the start and end. Checking whether something is `in` the range is done by checking `compareTo()` with the start and end.

Comment: Thank you.  I was misunderstanding how `in` was checked.